# unique lock and condition variable - explicitly calling unlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std

I found an example code which demonstrates how to use a condition variable :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

deque<int> qu;
mutex mu;
condition_variable cond;

void fun1()
{
     int count = 100;
     while (count > 0)
     {
          unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
          qu.push_front(count);
          locker.unlock();  // explicit unlock 1
          cond.notify_one();
          --count;
     }
}

void fun2()
{
     int data = 0;
     while(data != 1)
     {
          unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
          cond.wait(locker, [](){ return !(qu.empty()); });
          data = qu.back();
          qu.pop_back();
          locker.unlock(); // explicit unlock 2
          cout<<"data: "<<data<<endl;
     }
}

int main()
{
     thread t1(fun1);
     thread t2(fun2);
     t1.join();
     t2.join();
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

I think that explicitly calling unlock is not necessary. However in fun1 calling it before notify_one might increase a performace, right ? Why unlock is called in fun2 (in each iteration unlock is called implicitly, so doing it explicitly make no sense) ?

Comment: Maybe they want to unlock before the expensive `cout <<` operation?

Comment: The reason the lock is released in `fun1` is that `cond.wait()` will need to wake up twice without it (once for `notify_one()`, and again to lock `mu`).  As for `fun2`, you generally want to release locks as soon as you can, which you could do through narrowing scope (`{...}`) or the explicit `unlock()` call.

Comment: code that calls `unique_lock::unlock()` stinks.

Answer (score 2):

std::unique_lock use the RAII pattern.

That means its doesn't need to explicitly call unlock on mutex. This provides exception safety i.e in case of exception after locking the mutex and before explicitly unlocking it it automatically gets unlocked as it goes out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

It seems misleading to me. Locking with a mutex is required to use condition variables. This example uses the same mutex for multiple shared variables (`cond` and `qu`).

I think, it will not work properly if `fun1` or `fun2` runs on more than one thread.

Below would be more clear:

```
mutex mu;
mutex mu_for_cv;
condition_variable cond;

void fun1()
{
     int count = 100;
     while (count > 0)
     {
          unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
          qu.push_front(count);
          {
              unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu_for_cv);
              cond.notify_one();
          }
          --count;
     }
}

void fun2()
{
     int data = 0;
     while(data != 1)
     {
          {
               unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu_for_cv);
               cond.wait(locker, [](){ return !(qu.empty()); });
          }
          unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
          if (!qu.empty())
          {
              data = qu.back();
              qu.pop_back();
              cout<<"data: "<<data<<endl;
          }
     }
}
```

Also, it'd be better to check the queue is not empty in `fun2` to defense against [spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

Comment: "This example uses the same mutex for multiple shared variables (cond and qu)."..." think, it will not work properly if fun1 or fun2 runs on more than one thread." - that is not correct. You can absolutely use the same mutex to protect several variables. (You may have an incorrect mental model of what a mutex does).